# Talking at irregular intervals

Tags: word-usage, american-english

One of my friend speaks sporadically (that is, not often) to me.
How to express this in correct tense and words.
How to ask him about this.

"Why you are talking sporadically to me?" is this correct

FYI - This my first post. If I have done any wrong tagging please forgive.

Comment: Your sentence is oddly phrased.  It makes me think of the following nonsense conversation: "Hi... ...  well ... around the... the thing is... ... ... ... the!"  "Why are you talking sporadically to me?"  That is, the *present progressive* combined with the unlikely term *sporadically* makes me think of a particularly unlikely interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*My answer is now edited according to the comments below. Thank you.*

---

First of all, the sentence as you put it seems somehow unnatural. Better would be to reformulate it (using *negative* and *plural*) to something like:

**Why don't we speak** (to each other) **more often/more regularly?**

---

If you would insist on your structure (*using positive*), the better way would be to use *present simple* tense:

**Why do you so rarely talk to me?**

where you can replace the word *rarely* with other words here suggested such as:   "occasionally" or yours "sporadically".

---

In general, your sentence is grammatically correct, but it is not the way native speaker would say it.

Comment: Your first rephrasing is fine, but the second one seems decidedly unnatural to me. *Seldom* is seldom used nowadays anyway, but quite apart from that, *rarely* is normally used before rather than after the verb, and "do-support" is more common than present continuous in such contexts. More credible would be *"Why do you so rarely talk to me?"*, but to be honest I'm not convinced *any* variation on that particular theme would be particularly natural in modern speech.

Comment: This answer does not address the question of if the tense is correct. It could also confuse the question asker by making them think their use of sporadically is totally incorrect.

Comment: @ccanduc: What you said is precisely why I upvoted this question. _Why don't we talk more often?_ is the way I'd say it.

Comment: @Fumble - How about, "Why do we talk so infrequently?" Still unnatural?

Comment: J.R.: That version seems unremarkable to me. I think the fact that it uses **we** rather than **you** probably makes a difference too. In OP's context the implication is that the "communication shortfall" is primarily being laid at the door of the person being addressed, rather than the speaker (or both of them collectively). It just seems to me the most natural way of expressing that is to ask *why he **doesn't** talk more often*, rather than asking why he [does] talk so infrequently.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for your comments, especially about the _rarely_ case. It also seams to me that question with negative is somehow more natural. I think you should make your own answer to have it all right together somewhere.

Comment: @FumbleFingers or should I improve my answer? I am always confused in these situations.

Comment: @MasterPJ - Feel free to improve you answer, if you think this conversation can help you do that. No one will feel insulted or feel like you're "stealing" our ideas.

Comment: I think the most natural phrasing I would use is:  "How come you hardly ever talk to me?"  This lower register "folksy" wording helps put the other at ease and they're more likely to open up and answer you. It also implies that you'd be willing to interact more frequently.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of words I can think of, depending on what meaning you are trying to convey:

[Intermittently](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intermittently) & [Occasionally](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occasionally) refer to a time between your friend speaking to you where the amount of time between times does not follow a pattern

[Periodically](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/periodically) would indicate that there is a regular amount of time between each time your friend talks to you (such as at 10:00 every day, or every Monday)

All will use the form **Why you are [word here] talking to me?**

If you desire the amount of talking to increase, then something like **Why you are**  *Only* **[word here] talking to me?** would work

Answer (score 1):

*[Sporadically](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sporadic)* means

> happening sometimes; not regular or continuous

It is a neutral term.

You seem unhappy with the pattern of your friend's communication. It is not as frequent as you would like. Probably a better word would be *[infrequently](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/infrequent?q=infrequently)*

> not happening very often

While this can be a neutral term, in this context it suggests that you would like it to be *more* frequent.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your original question should be corrected with: ("One of my friends") - otherwise it is correct.
2. Your question to your friend is grammatically correct.
3. Your question to your friend sounds somewhat unnatural. But not very unnatural.
   It sounds more natural as:
   "Why do you speak to me sporadically?"

Sporadically is a word that is not used very often. So it is unusual to hear it in this context - but replacing it with "more often" would not actually express what you are trying to ask!